# Removing NaN from legend in Heatmap using geopandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, legend, geopandas

Im tring to plot a heatmap of Mirai botnet infections per country using geopandas. I have a geodataframe which is structured as follows:

```
geometry    Country_Code    Infection_Rate
0   MULTIPOLYGON (((11108970.260 445285.130, 11108...   IDN 0.01616
6   POLYGON ((3008931.293 3740791.337, 3007063.917...   NaN nan
7   MULTIPOLYGON (((3009012.519 3740778.293, 30089...   CYP 0.06845
8   MULTIPOLYGON (((6915098.813 3796247.587, 69170...   IND 0.0076
```

As becomes clear from the structure, there are some missing values, as the infection rate is not known for some countries

I plot the heatmap as follows:

```
## Some plot settings
colors = 6
cmap = 'Blues'
figsize = (16, 10)
plotvar = 'Infection_Rate'
scheme = 'equalinterval'
title = 'Infection rate per country (%)'
lables = ['0', '1', '2', '3','4','5']

## Create the plot
ax = geoinfect.plot(plotvar, cmap=cmap, figsize=figsize, k = colors, scheme = scheme,  legend=True)
ax.set_title(title, fontdict={'fontsize': 20}, loc='left')
ax.set_axis_off()
ax.set_xlim([-1.5e7, 1.7e7])
legend.set_bbox_to_anchor((.52, .4))

## Highlight missing values in grey
geoinfect[geoinfect.isna().any(axis=1)].plot(ax=ax, color='#D3D3D3')
```

This gives me the following result: [Heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6HXO.png)

Apart from poor styling, my main issue with this plot is that the first label of the legend reads "nan-0.21"instead of "0-0.21"

Is there a possibility for me to manually edit the legend in such a way that the first label states "0-0.21"?

Excuses if this is an obvious mistake, im rather new to programming :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are plotting your missing values separately, you can plot only those rows without NaNs first, so your legend will naturally be 0-.

```
ax = geoinfect[~geoinfect.isna().any(axis=1)].plot(plotvar, cmap=cmap, figsize=figsize, k = colors, scheme = scheme,  legend=True)

ax.set_title(title, fontdict={'fontsize': 20}, loc='left')
ax.set_axis_off()
ax.set_xlim([-1.5e7, 1.7e7])
legend.set_bbox_to_anchor((.52, .4))

## Highlight missing values in grey
geoinfect[geoinfect.isna().any(axis=1)].plot(ax=ax, color='#D3D3D3')
```

Answer (score 0):

First, modify the geodataframe before you plot the output. You can replace the 'nan' values present in the 'Infection_Rate' column with '0's. 
The following code should yield you the desired output.

```
geodataframe.Infection_Rate = geodataframe.Infection_Rate.replace({"nan": "0"})
```

And now you can go with plotting the heatmap using the above dataframe.

Comment: This gives me the following error: TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=float64)' and 'str'. Also, I would like to plot the missing values in grey, so it becomes clear for what countries the data is missing. So i do not think this provides a solution to the problem

Comment: @NickHoSamSooi Please provide a sample of the dataframe which can be used to reproduce the problem. The geodataframe that you provided cannot be loaded into a dataframe for reproducing the problem.